# Partial Load from Ember Model

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I have a model as such;

```
Logics.Files = DS.Model.extend({
    Field1: DS.attr('string'),
    Field2: DS.attr('string'),
    date_changed: DS.attr('date'),
    status: DS.attr('number'),

});
```

and when it is loaded from Django-REST all the fields have data coming from the server but when loaded into the model only date_changed and status are being filled in. Im not sure what is causing this?

Comment: We need more details: model definition, serializer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember is an 'opinionated' framework and it really expects attribute names to begin with a lowercase letter.  You should go with the flow and adopt the lowercase convention.